# How to execute jquery inside a Modal window?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I need to fire some actions when the state of a **textfield** is focused.

This code works (tested) fine if the textfield its a standard inline element. 
But it does not work if the textfield is inside a **Modal window**. I guess that the modal window is hidden at the moment the jquery library is loaded and then the problem.

How can I get this working?

```
    $('#name').focus(function() {
console.log('do something');
});
```

Comment: is the modal dialog dynamically loaded or static one

Comment: the modal is load with user interaction (when a link is clicked)

Comment: can you share the modal loading code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess that the modal window is hidden at the moment the jQuery
>   library is loaded and then the problem.

you guessed correctly, probably you load the content of your modal dialog after a certain event.

Now the code:

```
$('#name').focus(function() {
console.log('do something');
});
```

is probably attached to the $(document).ready() event which fires on each loading of a new document but dose not fire when an ajax call is completed

To overcome this problem you need to attach a delegate for the loading event of the dialog that will run your required function.
See on API or LIVE depending on your jQuery Version http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you want you can just use a generic delegate for each click event that is made and try to attach your focus event after each click is made like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#name", function() {
    $(this).focus(function() {
        console.log('do something');
    });
});
```

This will try to attach the focus function to the #name element after each click is made, that is if the #name element exists.

Comment: I get an error with your code. #name is the id of the textfield ? or it is the id of the link which opens the modal windows?

Comment: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document).on("click", "#edit-name", function() {
    $(this).focus(function() {
        console.log('do something');
    });
})')`

Comment: If there was something wrong with the code i gave you please note that so others can see that or i could fix my post...