# How to fire an jquery action when a div is appended?

Tags: jquery

I need to fire an jquery action when a div is appended.

Something like:

```
if ($('div#myDiv').is_appended()) {
console.log('the div has been appended');
}
```

Is this possible?

**Why do I need this**

This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083511/how-to-execute-jquery-inside-a-modal-window) where I have I modal div which is loaded after the jquery library, then I can't target the element in it.

Now I'm trying to do something when the modal div is load, not sure if I get it done though,

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the first place? Maybe there’s a better way.

Comment: No, events are fired for user actions. Since this is being added by code, what you should do is tie your function to whatever's doing the adding.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979738/fire-jquery-event-on-div-change) should answer your question.

Comment: @minitech look at the bottom of my question (just edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in a cross-browser way, not yet. There is a draft specification for *mutation observers* which would allow it (more on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers)), but it's only implemented in recent WebKit-based browsers and Firefox.

There's almost always a better approach available, such as triggering the action from the code appending the `div`. In the worst case (and I mean "worst"), you could use polling every (say) 100ms and detect the new `div`. But again, there's almost always a better way.

Comment: Did you know this off the top of your head??

Comment: @Dom: I'm quite a pathetic geek. :-)